# Thumnail issue on wordpress site?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, widget, thumbnails

I have a new wordpress site, using the "Magazine Style" theme.  When I create a new post it adds it to a sidebar widget, and is supposed to show a thumbnail of the user that posted it, but it doesn't and I just get a icon saying "No Thumb".  Does anyone know how to change this please?

Here's my site address so you can see the problem:

[Techpatrol.eu](http://techpatrol.eu)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: this usually happen for 2 reason
1) you need to place at least one image in your post ( i noticed you have video but no images ). that will be automatically set as ur thumb
2) in your post editor on the right bar menu you should find a small check that allow you to have thumbnails, make sure it's checked

Comment: @stabcode, he claims that it's supposed to show a thumbnail of the *user*, not a featured image. @user2741105, are you sure it's supposed to show a user image? Where is the user supposed to set their thumbnail? Wordpress has no native support for user portraits, but it does support Avatars for commenters. Take a look in your dashboard at `Settings > Discussion > Avatars`.

Comment: @stabcode Thanks very much for the info - I'll give that a try!

JPLew - Perhaps stabcode is right - maybe it is a thumbnail of the post and not the user - I had assumed it was a user photo, but perhaps not, as I checked the Avatar settings, and I do have a picture associated with the user I was posting as.

Thanks a lot for both your help! :)

Comment: Hi, I can confirm that in in Settings > Discussions > Avatars, the user I'm posting as has a avatar pic set.  I have also created a test post with an image in it, but that hasn't made a difference to the thumbnails.  

http://techpatrol.eu/photography-test-post/

Appreciate all the help everyone, got any more ideas please? :)

Comment: ;) np hope it work EDIT: just read... i'll check what else it can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i tried to upload ur theme to my wordpress. the problem is the thumb highlithed image

open your wordpress setup manager at youwebsite/wp-admin/
go to articles
open any article and on the right panel you find "set higlighted image"

done ;)

that's my test on my wp, you can see i added the thumb image to the last article
[image: here my test]

Comment: Thank you very much - that was it!  Thanks again stab code, you're a star!